# How to solve problem when inserting data in database, Yii2?

Tags: php, database, yii2

I can't insert data in the database. I'm using yii2 advanced.

I have 3 tables: the default user table, post, and category. Each post has one category, and one category can have many posts.
But when I click on 'Save' in my create form - nothing happens, the page just refreshes. The post table is still empty.

Here's PostController

```
    namespace frontend\controllers;

    use Yii;
    use yii\web\Controller;
    use frontend\models\CreateForm;
    use frontend\models\Category;
    use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;


    class PostController extends Controller
    {
public function actionCreate()
{
    if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
    {
        return $this->redirect(['/site/login']);

    }

    $model = new CreateForm();
    $category = Category::find()->all();
    $items = ArrayHelper::map($category, 'id', 'name');
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    {
        if ($model->save())
        {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash(
                'success',
                true

            );
            return $this->refresh();
        } else
            {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash(
                    'success',
                    false
                );
            }

    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'items' => $items
    ]);



}
```

This is CreateForm model

```
    namespace frontend\models;

    use yii\base\Model;
    use frontend\models\Post;
    use Yii;


    class CreateForm extends Model
    {
        public $category;
        public $title;
        public $content;

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'category' => 'Category',
        'title' => 'Title',
        'content' => 'Content',
    ];

}

public function save()
{
    $post = new Post();
    $post->user_id = Yii::$app->user->id;
    $post->category_id = $this->category;
    $post->title = $this->title;
    $post->content = $this->content;
    $post->created_at = time();


}

   }
```

And this the view

```
    use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
    use yii\bootstrap\Html;

    $form = ActiveForm::begin();
    echo $form->field($model, 'category')->dropDownList($items);
    echo $form->field($model, 'title')->textInput();
    echo $form->field($model, 'content')->textInput();
    echo Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
    ActiveForm::end();
```

What am I doing wrong, I can't understand

Comment: Your method `save` in `CreateForm` is not saving a new post, just assigning the values. You also might add validation rules in `CreateForm`. Read [Creating Forms](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-forms) and [Validating Input](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation) in the Guide.

Comment: Were you using [Gii](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-gii)? Gii can generate what you want. But without using yii\base\Model

Answer (score 1):

Ok. All I had to do is to add `$post->save()` in the end of my save method in CreateForm.